# C: free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, free, realloc

I have a program in which I try to read two lines of 40 characters. When something goes wrong or the program ends, I free array.

I'm getting an error message free(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

I think the problem is in the last cycle, but I can't solve it.

```
char *str = NULL;
size_t  capacity = 0;
char **maska;
int rMaska=2, cMaska = 40;
maska =(char**)malloc (rMaska*sizeof(*maska));
    
    
    for (int a = 0; a < rMaska; a++)
        maska[a]=(char *) malloc (cMaska*sizeof(**maska));

    i=0;
    printf("Maska:\n");
    while ( getline (&str, &capacity, stdin) != -1)
    {
        if (i==rMaska)
    {
        printf("incorrect entry.\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
            free (maska[i]);
        free(maska);

        return 0;
    }   
        if( strlen(str) != (unsigned int) cMaska )
            {
                printf("incorrect entry.\n");
                
                for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
                    free (maska[i]);
                free(maska);
                    
                return 0;
            }
            
        for (int i = 0; i < cMaska-1; i++)
            {
                if ( (str[i] != '#') && (str[i] != '.') )
                {
                    printf("incorrect entry.\n");
                    for (int a = 0; a < rMaska; a++)
                        free (maska[a]);
                    free(maska);
                    
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        
        strcpy(maska[i], str);
        i++;
    }
    
    free(str);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rMaska; i++)
        free (maska[i]);
    free(maska);
```

Comment: What's str? Please post code that readers can compile.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not related to your problem, but you should really not use tons of variables with same name. You have at least 5 variables called `i`. For the outer one a definition is missing.

Comment: What is your input? When do you get the error message? What is `capacity?` Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've already added those variables there.

Comment: Note that you have multiple variables named `i`. It's quite confusing.

Comment: #.####.#.#.###..########..###.##..##.##
.##.##...####.###..####.#####..######.#     
the input at which it falls, this input should be valid

Comment: For debugging you should print different error message that can be distinguished. Also you should run your program in a debugger. It should tell you where you get a dump and you can watch variable content while stepping through the code.

Comment: When I commented on the last cycle, it worked normally. Can there be a problem?

Comment: How do you terminate your input after second line? Are you sure that you do not enter this `if (i==rMaska)`? If you reach your last loop, there is a `return` statement missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check that the string you input has strlen 40, and then if it has do a strcpy of the string to an array element whose allocated size is 40. But strcpy copies the trailing NUL too, that is it copies 41 characters. So you are, as the saying goes, doing a poo in the heap

Comment: but if input has length 40 it should hit the condition `if( strlen(str) != (unsigned int) cMaska )` then there is a proper `free` OR did i miss something?

Comment: csavvy I think you are missing that  if strlen(s) is N, strcpy( dest, s) copies N+1 characters. strlen does not include the trailing NUL aka 0

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `i` variable used in the while and for loops messed it all up.
I would define a different variable to use in the while loop (instead of `i`), the fact that the for loops inside also use it is very confusing, and its also something that can later on create bugs.

And by the way you didn't free `str` in case of incorrect entry.